# Show column value of one of left joins

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

In this Query shows one row if `SAL.ID_AMENAZA` exists in `MFT` or `MFA` schemas, but i want to show `MFT.ID_AMENAZA` or `MFA.ID_AMENAZA` (if exist in any table) in the resulting row.

In my actual query i dont require the ID_AMENAZA. How can i show?

```
SELECT SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA
FROM AGR_SALVAGUARDAS SAL 
     LEFT JOIN AGR_MIT_FREC_TIPO MFT
     ON SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA = MFT.ID_SALVAGUARDA AND MFT.ID_AMENAZA = 5043 
     LEFT JOIN AGR_MIT_FREC_ACT MFA
     ON SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA = MFA.ID_SALVAGUARDA AND MFA.ID_AMENAZA = 5043   
WHERE MFT.ID_SALVAGUARDA IS NOT NULL OR
      MFA.ID_SALVAGUARDA IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA
```

I need to obtain a table like this:

```
ID_SALVAGUARDA | DESCRIPCION | EFICACIA | ID_AMENAZA
5061           | PRE-01      | 100      | 5043
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA, 5043 as ID_AMENAZA
FROM AGR_SALVAGUARDAS SAL 
     LEFT JOIN AGR_MIT_FREC_TIPO MFT
     ON SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA = MFT.ID_SALVAGUARDA AND MFT.ID_AMENAZA = 5043 
     LEFT JOIN AGR_MIT_FREC_ACT MFA
     ON SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA = MFA.ID_SALVAGUARDA AND MFA.ID_AMENAZA = 5043   
WHERE MFT.ID_SALVAGUARDA IS NOT NULL OR
      MFA.ID_SALVAGUARDA IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA;
```

because your query guarantees that there is at least one match.

However, the more general solution is:

```
SELECT SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA,
       cOALESCE(MFT.ID_AMENAZA, MFA.ID_AMENAZA) as ID_AMENAZA
. . .
```

The function `COALESCE()` returns the first value that is not `NULL` in its list of arguments.

Comment: Thank you, finally i used the Coalesce an in `GROUP BY` i modified for this: `GROUP BY SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DENOMINACION, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA, MFT.ID_AMENAZA, MFA.ID_AMENAZA`

Answer (score 1):

You can `coalesce` for this.

```
SELECT 
  SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, 
  SAL.DESCRIPCION, 
  SAL.EFICACIA, 
  COALESCE( MFT.ID_AMENAZA, MFA.ID_AMENAZA) as ID_AMENAZA
```

This will return the first ID that is not null.